# Photo collage with jquery and html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-ui, html5-canvas

I want to organize four images separately and then combine into a canvas with jquery. How can I do a collage?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I searched lots of code from some sites but I don't want to complex collage. I want to combine just four images. I am very new for jquery.

Comment: Do you just want the four images displayed in a 2 x 2 grid? Do you want them in a 1 x 4 row? What exactly are you hoping to achieve, in terms of how the images will be displayed?

Comment: Yes, I want the four images displayed in a 2 x 2 grid.

Comment: To put images on html canvas you will need to use javascript--no jquery needed or helpful here. In particular, you can put images on the canvas using `context.drawImage(yourImageObject,x,y)`. Here's a useful tutorial on html canvas: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001654/index.html. Try writing some code and come back to Stackoverflow with another question if you have problems. Good luck with your collage.

Comment: Thanks. Have you got a code sample that I could improve?

Comment: Sigh! Read this chapter from my previous link you will learn how to draw an image on the html canvas. If you read that chapter you will probably know how to do your collage--it contains your "starter code". If not, come back to Stackoverflow with another question if your have problems. Here's a link to the chapter teaching how to draw an image on the canvas: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001654/ch04.html#preloading_images

Answer (score 3):

To create a canvas with Jquery try:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
$('body').append($(canvas));
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 1000;
```

You can replace 'body' with whatever you'd like. To draw your images do this:

```
var image1 = new Image();
var image2 = new Image();
image1.src = "/src/image1.png"
image2.src = "/src/image1.png"

context.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, 500, 500)
context.drawImage(image2, 500, 0, 500, 500)
context.drawImage(image1, 0, 500, 500, 500)
context.drawImage(image2, 500, 500, 500, 500)
```

Good luck